# python 3 flask sqlalchemy, how to do full text search in database

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Since options like `m-search` or `whoosh sqlalchemy` aren't available anymore. What is the way to go?

I tried the basic sqlalchemy like feature-
`uploads = Uploads.query.filter(Uploads.title.like(search)).all()`

But it is not a full text search.
I cannot make `elasticsearch` work with mysql db.

Are there any other options available?
Thanks

Comment: We need to see a lot more detail here.  What is the definition of the `Uploads` model?  What is `search`?  What, exactly, does the query return?  What is an example of a record that you expected it to find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

> Uploads.query.filter(Uploads.title.**contains**(search)).all()

For me, this is working for all searches in MySQL DB.

For elastic search, you need to use

> match_phrase_prefix and append it into the must_list

> **Exe**  {"match_phrase_prefix": {title: {"query": search}}}

And one more thing you need to execute it manually with **es_db.search**